# Algorithm for News Ranking?

Tags: algorithm, ranking

Now. I build a formula for news to get list hot news.
have any factor as pageview, time,content.
what does a solution for this problem?
Thanks

Comment: How 'bout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783892/implementing-the-hacker-news-ranking-algorithm-in-sql?rq=1

Comment: Where are you getting the feed? What does the data look like? What have you tried?

Comment: @MattBall: now, i have pageview. as hacker news have upvote and downvote

Comment: Now. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Hello, Have you found a solution or more info about how to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a [machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) approach for this problem.

1. Extract your features, and give each a numeric value (you can use
   the [Bag of Words model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) for content). Note that some [feature selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) algorithm might be needed.
2. Manually label large enough set of examples - and give each of them a score according to its importance.
3. Use [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) and build a function that evaluates each article and gives it a score.
4. Now that you have your regression function, you can use it to give score to each article. Use it to achieve the raw score.
5. For post processing - combine this score with the time in a second function to get the article's final score. [@MattBall's suggested link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3783892/572670) seems like reasonable approach.