# Reddit Style Score Degridation Over Time In MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to create a reddit style score degradation system for entries on a system. I've got a MySQL view setup to calculate the total "Score" (sum of all up/down votes). I'm having trouble creating a simple, but effective system for moving entries down the page (so that newer entries end up at the top, but a high score can move entries to the top that would otherwise have aged off)...

Here's the closest bit of SQL I've been able to create thus far:

```
(SUM(v.Score) - (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.Genesis, NOW()) *
              IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.Genesis, NOW()) > 1440,
                    0.1, 0.003))
) as "Weight",
```

v.Score is a 1 or a -1 dependent on user votes. t.Genesis is the timestamp on the entry itself.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a better option than doing a sum of all up/down votes. You can look here : http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html
And you can add a time var, if the data is out of date, you decrease the scoring

Comment: Post sample data and expected results pls...

Comment: @J-CFOREST - While that looks promising... I'm unsure how I'd actually implement a time variable in it? Thoughts?

Comment: And then you use `ORDER BY Weight DESC`??

Comment: @RickJames currently, yes.

Comment: What is the question?  Looking for a "scoring algorithm"?  Implementation problems?  Performance?  Something else?

Comment: I'm looking for a scoring algorithm, yes.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to use a sort of exponential decay for the relevance of time as a ranking parameter. For example:

```
SELECT 
    article, ranking 
FROM (
   SELECT 
       article,
       (upvotes + downvotes) AS Total,
       (upvotes - downvotes) AS Score,
       (EXP(-(Published - Genesis) * Constant / 86400) * (Score / Total)) AS Ranking
   FROM Table) 
ORDER BY ranking DESC
```

Where `Published` is the time of publishing, `Genesis` is some really early date, and `Constant` is a scaling factor, to determine how late the weight should drop to zero at:

*For example:* if you want to give all posts a very small score advantage after 7 days from now (say 0.1) then `-ln(0.1) / 7` is your `Constant`.

`Score / Total` for the average rating rather than the absolute value and `86400` for a one day in seconds (assuming that's how you're measuring your time).

Once again, apologies for my lack of knowledge on **SQL** functions, I know that `EXP` is definitely possible, only the time difference function can be adjusted in order to get the time difference in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the same ranking algorithm than Hacker News :

[Implementing the Hacker News ranking algorithm in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783892/implementing-the-hacker-news-ranking-algorithm-in-sql)

@OMG Ponies solution:

```
 SELECT x.*
    FROM POSTS x
    JOIN (SELECT p.postid, 
                 SUM(v.vote) AS points
            FROM POSTS p
            JOIN VOTES v ON v.postid = p.postid
        GROUP BY p.postid) y ON y.postid = x.postid
ORDER BY (y.points - 1)/POW(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(x.timestamp))/3600)+2, 1.5) DESC
   LIMIT n
```

x.timestamp is your t.Genesis, v.vote is your v.Score

Comment: So this has a small flaw in that newer posts aren't ranked near the top and posts that have equal points seem to be ordered oldest to newest? It's essentially a ORDER BY points, genesis